# CakePHP Validation Regex

Tags: php, regex, cakephp

I have a quick regex question that I figured someone might know off the top of their head. What would the regex be for CakePHP's validation be if I only want to allow upper/lower alphanumber, spaces, punctuation, and quotes? This is what I have, but it's off:

```
 'rule' => array('custom', '/[a-z0-9\x20\x21\x2E\x3A\x3B\x3F\x2C\x27\x22]{0,600}/i'),
```

From what I get, the a-z0-9 covers alphanumeric, but shouldn't the \xXX cover the punctuation with the ASCII hex codes? And then the {0,600] means a length of 0-600 characters, and i means upper and lower. What am I missing?

For example: valid: This is a "valid text", which contains ' and punctuation!

invalid: This is an obvious XSS attempt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
^([\d\w\s?!\.;:,'"\/\[\]\(\)=\+-]*)$
```

should work? You should provide examples of what texts you consider to be valid and which are invalid.

```
preg_match('/^([\d\w\s?!\.;:,'"\/\[\]\(\)=\+-]*)$/', $string);
```

Comment: Thanks Jack, but would you be able to explain which part means what? I'm trying to learn regex, but it's a lot to learn at once :)

Comment: Also: your regex is throwing this error: preg_match(): No ending delimiter '^' found [CORE/Cake/Utility/Validation.php, line 781]

Comment: The `^` means the start of the string and the `$` means the end of the string.  It searches the the whole string and makes sure that from beginning to end, the only valid characters are numbers, letters, punctuation, etc.

Comment: Are you sure you're typing the pattern correctly? This works with no error `preg_match('/^([\d\w\s?!\.;:,'"\/\[\]\(\)=\+-]*)$/', $string);` cause it sounds like a php syntax error.

Comment: Ahh ok I figured out that the problem was in my Controller. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 1):

As long as you know you want it to be ASCII, just use the character ranges

```
$input = "this is a \n string\n";
echo preg_match("/^[ -~]{0,600}$/", $input);  // output is 0 (false)
$input = "this is a string";
echo preg_match("/^[ -~]{0,600}$/", $input);  // output is 1 (true)
```

Whenever I deal with ASCII I find the specific ranges much easier.
So basically you want the start of the string to be anything within a space and ~, which are all visible characters.  And then you have a 0-600 character limit, and $ signifies the end of the string